# the function dfs_edges of networkx library can not find all the edges

Tags: python, networkx

I want to use the `dfs_edges` of networkx library find all the reachable edges of the source node, but it cannot find all the edges completely, my code is:

```
import networkx as nx
from networkx import dfs_edges

nodes = [0,1,2,3,4]
edges = [(0,1),(0,2),(1,2),(1,3),(2,3),(0,4)]
DG = nx.DiGraph()
DG.add_nodes_from(nodes)
DG.add_edges_from(edges)

print(list(dfs_edges(DG,1)))
```

the result is `[(1, 2), (2, 3)]`, but the `(1,3)` is also the reachable edge of node `1`, why the result dosen't contain it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using edge_dfs rather than dfs_edges will solve this.

- edge_dfs(G, source) Continues until it has visited every edge reachable by the source.
- dfs_edges(G, source) Stops once it has visited all the nodes the source node can
  reach.

  ```
  import networkx as nx
  from networkx import edge_dfs

  nodes = [0,1,2,3,4]
  edges = [(0,1),(0,2),(1,2),(1,3),(2,3),(0,4)]
  DG = nx.DiGraph()
  DG.add_nodes_from(nodes)
  DG.add_edges_from(edges)

  print(list(edge_dfs(DG,1)))  # [(1, 2), (2, 3), (1,3)]
  ```